# Recalculate all lights baking after script is over in unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a procedural dungeon in Unity, after I calculate the dungeon (array based), I use a for loop to instantiate it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++){   
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++){
     if(dung[i,j] == 0)
        //Instantiate floor prefab
     else
        //Instantiate wall prefab  
    }  
}
```

My problem comes after this is done, the floor and wall prefabs have an emissive material attached and because they are created after the scene is loaded, Unity doesn't calculate the emissive reflection.

Is there any way to do the baking after the script is done?

Comment: Are you creating the dungeon at runtime of the game or in the editor? If you do it at runtime, there is no way to bake this anymore, as baking per definition happens before runtime, because you don't want to do this expensive operation at runtime.

Comment: Im creating it at runtime because I need a script be executed to create it. I dont find a way to solve this problem.